# Get text game to go into another room and collect items

Tags: python

I need to be able to enter different rooms with command like `go north`, and to add items to the inventory by typing `get` then the item's name. But when I run it and try to get an item, it prints my `else` statement continuously. I don't even know if I am getting to the other rooms.

```py
# this is a text game for my class IT140 intro into scripting
# Derek Pruitt 10/01/2021

# this is to have speech to text
# NOTE: user needs to install this with pip install pyttsx3
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

# changing the voice to a female voice
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

# setting up new voice rate
engine.setProperty('rate', 125)

# engine.stop()
# welcome the player
engine.say('Hello, welcome to my text based game!')
print('Hello, welcome to my text based game!')
engine.say('what is your name')
engine.runAndWait()
player = input('What is your name\n')
engine.say(player + 'we welcome you')
engine.runAndWait()

# creating player inventory, starts with nothing
inventory = []
# all the rooms with directional commands to connecting rooms, items in each room
rooms = {
    'Cabin': {'West': 'Coat room'},
    'Coat room': {'South': 'Operating room', 'East': 'Cabin', 'item': 'Key'},
    'Operating room': {'South': 'Chemical room', 'North': 'Cabin',
                       'West': 'Armoire', 'East': 'Prayer room', 'item': 'Oil'},
    'Armoire': {'East': 'Operating room', 'item': 'Crossbow'},
    'Prayer room': {'West': 'Operating room', 'North': 'Sleeping chamber',
                    'item': 'Holy cross'},
    'Sleeping chamber': {'South': 'Prayer room', 'item': 'The Skinner'},
    'Chemical room': {'North': 'operating room', 'East': 'Meat room',
                      'item': 'poison'},
    'Meat room': {'West': 'Chemical room', 'item': 'Cooked meat'}
}


def show_instructions():
    # print a main menu and the commands
    print("To quit the game at anytime, type 'Quit'.")
    print("Collect 6 items to win the game, or be killed by the Skinner.")
    print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")

# commands the player can use


# for putting items in player inventory
def get_item(item):
    if command == 'get':
        inventory.append(item)
        print(inventory)
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    show_instructions()
    command = input()
    while command != 'Quit':
        if command == 'go west':
            print(rooms['Coat room'])
            rooms['Coat room']
            command = input()
        else:
            print('Please enter a valid command.')
            show_instructions()
        while rooms == rooms['Coat room']:
            if command == 'go south':
                print(rooms['Operating room'])
                rooms['Operating room']
                command = input()
            elif command == 'go east':
                print(rooms['Cabin'])
                rooms['Cabin']
                command == input()
            elif command == 'get ' '':
                get_item()

            else:
                print('Please enter a valid command.')
                show_instructions()
```

Comment: Which `else` statement does it print continuously?

Comment: What sequence of commands did you enter?

Comment: [Have a look here regarding asking homework questions on stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Can you also give us a bit of context of what you intending to do?

Comment: I'm not sure if it causes this problem, but `rooms == rooms['Coat room']` can never be true.

Comment: Also, you defined `get_item` as a function that takes one argument, but when you call it you pass no argument.

Comment: the first else statement. I can type go west, then when I type get key the else statement runs.

Comment: I need to be able to have the player enter different rooms, but only those that are connecting. I also need to be able to have the player pick up items. the player needs to have all 6 items before encounter the Skinner or they lose if they have all 6 they win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.. I will make a bullet list, listing everything that I found so far.

- **Case sensitivity**. Be careful with the instructions that you give to your user. You wrote "*go **S**outh*" but you compare with "*go **s**outh*".

> **NOTE:** This is also (very likely) the reason why you get your first `else`
> statement printed over and over again.. you didn't enter "*go west*"
> and `rooms == rooms['Coat room']` always equals to `false` and doesn't
> make any sense. So, you jump right back at the top of the first while,
> comparing again with "go west" and you are back in your `else` section.

- **State variables**. You need some sort of state variables that stores several aspects of the game. For example, a variable that stores the information in which room the user is at a moment. I assume that with `rooms['Coat room']` you wanted to update the room. This instruction is pointless. You need something like `current_room = rooms['Coat room']`. Other possible state variables could be `game_won: boolean` that indicates, if a player has won the game, `person_killed: boolean` that indicates, if a player was killed and lost the game, and `inventory: List[String]` you actually already have that one.
- **Loop**. Your nested loops don't make any sense. Why would you switch rooms to the coat room and then go into the nested loop. You can do something like:

*For whatever reason, I have to write a line here. Otherwise, Stackoverflow ruins my formatting.*

```
command = input()    
while command != 'Quit':
        while not person_killed and not game_won:
            # 1) execute command here 
            # => update all state variables (person_killed, item_inventory, game_won, current_room)
            # 2) print information to user
            # 3) check if game is over (if game_won or person_killed is true) and eventually break the loop.
```

- **Print statements**. You need print statements **after each action** that inform your user what actually happened after an executed command (for example after a room change).

Comment: this helps some, but Im still not sure how to get the item out of the room and add it to the inventory of the player. Also Im still a little new to python, how would I go about updating the variables? like, can I update the room they are in, and  do I that with IF statements?

Comment: Also, I used room['Coat room'], to put the player in that room, did I do it wrong?

Comment: @DerekPruitt you need to try to read my answer more carefully. Everything you asked for is already there. 1) Yes, you can update variables in if statements like this `if smth_is_true: # update variable here`. 2) Yes, this is wrong. You need smth like `current_room = rooms['Coat room']`

Answer (score -1):

Try using an else if style, like this.

```
user = input("left or right r for right l for left")

if user == "l"
print("you went left")

elif user == "r"
print("you went right")

elif user not in("r", "l")
print("invalid input")
exit()
```

or check [this](https://www.derekshidler.com/how-to-create-a-text-based-adventure-and-quiz-game-in-python/) link